# Comparing columns of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to compare columns from one tibble with another? For example I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c(5,7,6,2),
  col2 = c(5, 7, 4, 8))

df2 <- tibble( 
  col1 = c(5,7,6,2),
  col2 = c(5, 3, 5, 12))
```

I want to be able to compare `df1` with `df2` and get an output like this:

```
comparison <- tibble(
col1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
col2 = c (TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I would recommend rewriting this as "is there a way to ..." or "how do I ..." rather than "is there a package ..." (package-recommendation questions are technically off-topic for SO)

Comment: Hi. okay have amended the wording. just out of interest, why is package suggestion off-topic? Because the package might change so the answer wont be useful in the future?

Comment: Because it technically counts as looking for a resource that's outside of SO - it makes a bit more sense when thinking about other languages that aren't as package-centric as R

Comment: Okay makes sense - thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sotos points out in comments, `df1==df2` works! You need `(df1==df2) %>% as_tibble()` (parentheses required) if you want the result to be a tibble ...

If you want to work harder: in base R you can do this with `Map` or `mapply`:

```
Map(`==`,df1,df2) %>% as_tibble()
```

or in tidyverse:

```
map2(df1,df2,`==`) %>% as_tibble()
```

Comment: Why not simply `df1 == df2`?

Comment: Glad to have found this answer, as I'm looking to add a unit test for a function that parses a data file into a tibble. If you append `%>% all()` to the answer, you get a single TRUE/FALSE response indicating wether the tibbles are the same or not.